# How to call swift generic function from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generic-function

Please read the question.

I know that we can't call Swift generic methods from Objective-C as per this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78)

But in my case I have a project written in Objective-C and Swift. There is network library written in Swift having generic GET, POST, DELETE methods. For example below is GET method

```
public func get<T: ResponseDeserializer>(withDeserializer responseDeserializer: T, at relativePath: String? = nil, options: RestOptions = RestOptions(), callback: @escaping (APIResult<T.ResponseType>, HTTPURLResponse?) -> ()) {
    makeCall(relativePath, httpMethod: RestAPIManager.kGetType, payload: nil, responseDeserializer: responseDeserializer, options: options, callback: callback)
}
```

Where ResponseDeserializer is a protocol confirmed by few other classes.

Now my question is that is there any way to call above methods from Objective-C or should I implement a new network library for Objective-C.

I am looking for your valuable guidance.

Comment: it is not just about the _method_ only but all _parameters_ need to have an ObjC representation as well – which we don't know anything about, based on your current post.

Comment: please let me know if I have to post complete code though it is too large.

Answer (score 1):

No, even though it is a library, it is still written in Swift. And per the link you provided, you cannot call generic methods from Objective-C, since generics are a Swift feature.